# C# Way to validate test data

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm running a test where i need to validate data from a linux file. I've defined the path of the file is located (see below). Once i cat the file to read the data contents (irm_dwge_stt_l__xxxx.csv.ovr) how can i validate the data within this file

Also where i have defined the measurementName where can i define what measurements belong within this.

```
public string validateMeasurement(string measurementName, string domaianName)
{
    var processFilePath = "/inputs/ff/ff/actuals/" + measurementName + ".csv.ovr";
    var actualItemData = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor.RunLinuxcommand("cat " + processFilePath);

    return actualItemData;
}
```

Comment: How does this relates to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

One way of reading data in C# is to use [`File.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Running `cat` and capturing the output is probably not the way to go.

Comment: But then once the file is open how can i validate the data within it

Comment: What does validate mean in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

This C# example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time shows you how to read a file line by line.
You can then compare the file line by line to whatever data you are validating against.
Notice, this will probably only works if you are trying to validate a text file.

```
int counter = 0;  
string line;  

// Read the file and display it line by line.  
System.IO.StreamReader file =   
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    System.Console.WriteLine (line);  
    counter++;  
}  

file.Close();  
System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter);  
// Suspend the screen.  
System.Console.ReadLine();
```